General Base Rate Fallacy (from Principles of statistical analysis, Arias-Castro)
The book Principles of statistical analysis by Arias-Castro contains the following problem (problem 1.52, p. 18):
There are $m$ individuals, each having their own sensitivity and specificity ($\alpha_i$, $\beta_i$) for a (medical) test. Proportion $\pi$ of individuals is sick. Previously it was shown that if $\forall i$ $\alpha_i=\alpha$ and $\beta_i=\beta$, for an individual the probability of being sick given positive test is
$$
\mathbb{P}(\text{sick}|\text{positive test})=\frac{(1-\beta)\pi}{(1-\beta)\pi+\alpha(1-\pi)}
$$
Now we need to show that if $\alpha_i\neq\alpha_j$ and $\beta_i\neq\beta_j$ for (some) $i\neq j$, for a randomly (and uniformly) chosen individual the same probability equation applies with $\alpha=1/m\sum_i\alpha_i$ and $\beta=1/m\sum_i\beta_i$.
Confirmed by simulations, the right approach is to calculate the probability of "sick|test" for an average individual. I can understand how it to get there by considering $n$ hypothetical repeated testing (or even full replication of combinations of sick-test). In this case the probability space contains samples $(\gamma_{ij},\delta_{ij})$, $i=1,\dots,m$, $j=1,\dots,n$, where $\gamma_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$ is the test result (0 - negative, 1 - positive) for $i$-th individual on the $j$-th replication and $\delta_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$ is the indicator of being sick for $i$-th individual on the $j$-th replication (with condition $\sum_i\delta_{ij}=\pi m$ for each $j$).
It is easy to see that
$$
\alpha_i=\mathbb{P}(\text{positive test}|\text{not sick})=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n\gamma_{ij}(1-\delta_{ij})}{\sum_{k=1}^n(1-\delta_{ik})}
$$
$$
1-\beta_i=\mathbb{P}(\text{positive test}|\text{sick})=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n\gamma_{ij}\delta_{ij}}{\sum_{k=1}^n\delta_{ik}}
$$
So, from there I can show that averaging $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ and then substituting to the above equation for probability is equivalent to calculation of
$$
\frac{\#(\text{sick and positive test})}{\#(\text{positive test})}
$$
This line of thinking, while it works, is very convoluted. I am wondering if there is a simpler solution.
Also, here is another line of thought that instead of computing a probability for an average individual, computes an average probability: what if we expand the required probability:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\text{sick}|\text{positive test})=\sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb{P}(\text{sick}|\text{positive test and individual i is chosen})\mathbb{P}[i]
$$
here $\mathbb{P}[i]$ means the probability of choosing individual $i$. Since the individual is chosen uniformly, it equals to $1/m$. Hence we have:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\text{sick}|\text{positive test})=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb{P}(\text{sick}|\text{positive test and individual i is chosen})
$$
Then, the probability in the summation is
$$
\mathbb{P}(\text{sick}|\text{positive test and individual i is chosen})=\frac{(1-\beta_i)\pi}{(1-\beta_i)\pi+\alpha_i(1-\pi)}
$$
Hence, we get an average of probabilities. This formula doesn't have any practical use as individual $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are not known. So, we cannot estimate these probabilities from a single realization (here my idea of having $n$ hypothetical replicates helps). Nonetheless, something is wrong with this line of thinking as an estimation of the probability for a randomly chosen individual. My suspicion is that I misinterpret the meaning of $\mathbb{P}(\text{sick}|\text{positive test})$ here: it doesn't seem to mean the probability for an individual. But what is it then?


In this situation, we want to apply Bayes formula.

However, unlike the simple case, we have the addition of an additional variable which we want to average out. Here, the additional variable is $\alpha_i,\beta_i$, the subject-specific response to the test.

That does not change the Bayes formula. We still want to compute the ratio:
$$
p(\text{sick and positive}) / p(\text{positive})
$$

So what changes? The only thing that does change is that, in the more complex model, both of these probabilities need to be found by marginalizing out / averaging out the additional variables. In the simple model, $p(positive)$ is given by the model; in the complex model, we need to compute:
$$p(\text{positive}) = \int_{\alpha_i, \beta_i} p(\text{positive} | \alpha_i, \beta_i) p(\alpha_i, \beta_i)$$

Because the model is so simple, the marginalization simplifies in this case, as you have observed. The fact that there are subject-specific variations of the FPR and FNR do not matter for this calculation, only the average FPR and FNR.


Please note, however, that if the test has very different behavior in two subpopulations, then the conditional probabilities inside of each population will be very different. This is a major source of bias in real-life so please pay close attention to this in your own work.
edit: detailing the calculations slightly
$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{sick and positive})
&= P(\text{sick}) P(\text{positive} | \text{sick}) \\
&= P(\text{sick}) \int_\beta P(\text{positive} | \text{sick}, \beta) p(\beta | \text{sick}) \\
&= \pi \big( 1 - E(\beta | \text{sick}) \big)
\end{align}
$$
Similarly:
$$
P(\text{not_sick and positive}) = (1 - \pi) E(\alpha | \text{not_sick})
$$

Ok, got it. I just need to marginalize each probability p(sick and positive) and p(positive) separately over $(\alpha,\beta)$, put them into the ratio and I get the desired result. In my second approach I tried to do the marginalization, but somehow it was incorrect. I am still puzzled why it is incorrect. There I was putting p(sick|pos) = $\int p(sick|pos,\alpha,\beta)P(d\alpha,d\beta)$ and it doesn't work. Why?

Ah found the mistake: in marginalizing $P(sick|test) = \sum_i P(sick|positive|i)Q_i$ the term $Q_i$ mustn't be just probability of choosing a random person, it is also conditional on test: $Q_i=P(i|positive)$. This way everything agrees, but it would be difficult to arrive at closed form equation.

@mobiuseng Unless I'm wrong, you should be getting: P(sick and positive) = pi average (1-beta_i) in sick population; P(not_sick and positive) = (1 - pi) average (alpha) in not_sick population. P(positive) is the sum and the conditional is the ratio.

Yes, that's correct. Above is the alternative method of calculations. It is not useful in practice since $P(sick|positive|i)$ won't be available. Yet it is satisfying to see that both methods give the same result in simulations.
